# How can i pass background color as Prop in for loop?

Tags: vue.js

its me again!

so i have a own component:

```
<template>
<div class='mynewcomponent'>
  <v-layout>
    <v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
      <v-card v-bind:style="{ backgroundColor: this.myColor}">
        <!-- Picture
        <v-img
          src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/sunshine.jpg"
          height="200px"
        >
        </v-img>
         -->
        <v-card-title primary-title>
          <div>
              <slot name="header">Top western road trips</slot>
              <br>
              <slot name="TestDesciption">1,000 miles of wonder</slot>
          </div>
        </v-card-title>

        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn flat>Share</v-btn>
          <v-btn flat color="purple">Explore</v-btn>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn icon @click="show = !show">
            <v-icon>{{ show ? 'keyboard_arrow_down' : 'keyboard_arrow_up' }}</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>

        <v-slide-y-transition>
          <v-card-text v-show="show">
            I'm a thing. But, like most politicians, he promised more than he could deliver. You won't have time for sleeping, soldier, not with all the bed making you'll be doing. Then we'll go with that data file! Hey, you add a one and two zeros to that or we walk! You're going to do his laundry? I've got to find a way to escape.
          </v-card-text>
        </v-slide-y-transition>
      </v-card>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
   data: () => ({
    show: false,
    myColor:'#ffffff'
  })
}
</script>
```

and in my about.vue i load it in a for loop:

```
<template>
<div class='about'>
  <mynewcomponent v-for="(item,index) in 100"/>>

    <template v-slot:header>
      <h3 style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #3366ff">ID: 1234</span></h3>
    </template>
        <template v-slot:TestDesciption>
      <h3 style="text-align: left">example shit</h3>
    </template>
  </mynewcomponent>
</div>
</template>

<script>

import myNewComponent from '@/components/myNewComponent.vue'; // @ is an alias to /src
export default {
  name: 'about',
  components: {
    'mynewcomponent': myNewComponent
  }
}
</script>
```

now i want the even and odd Cards in other background color.
i tried everything what google says but whitout success.

i will pass the color if **index % 2 == 0** (even or odd)

how can i pass the color in the for loop ?

or can someone tell me a better way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method to bind the class attribute and pass the index as a parameter. For each line, you can evaluate and return a different class to this element.

You can check am example [here](https://codepen.io/aquilesb/pen/zVmRYV)

```js
methods:{
  spanClass: function(index) {
   return {
    in: index % 2 === 0,
    out: index % 2 !== 0
   }
  }
```

```css
li.in {
  background-color:red;
}

li.out {
  background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<template>
<div class='about'>
  <mynewcomponent v-for="(item,index) in 100"/>>

    <template v-slot:header>
      <h3 style="text-align: left;"><span :class="spanClass(item)">ID: 1234</span></h3>
    </template>
        <template v-slot:TestDesciption>
      <h3 style="text-align: left">example shit</h3>
    </template>
  </mynewcomponent>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: hmm i tried but nothing happend. Can i use this with my custom component (mynewcomponent?